# Observable for System.Windows.Point

Tags: wpf, observable, reactiveui

I added property in View:

```
[Reactive] public Point PositionLeftClick { get; set; } = new Point();
```

On mouse click I set property value.
And try use it as parameter for command parameter

```
this.WhenActivated(disposable =>
{
var positionLeftClickObservable = this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.PositionLeftClick);
this.BindCommand(this.ViewModel, x => x.CommandAddNodeWithUndoRedo, x => x.ItemAddNode, 
positionLeftClickObservable).DisposeWith(disposable);
});
```

But parameter value in command always 0,0

How I can fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, I wouldn't put a `[Reactive]` property in a View.  Normally I would delegate that to some ViewModel and bind it to the View.

ReactiveUI is an MVVM framework, and it works better when you provide a ViewModel for binding state to the View.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, my project is MVVM. I just try use Reactive in view too, because other  way is doesn't work

Comment: Rodney is correct. the `[Reactive]` fody won't work because that fody is designed to work with `ReactiveObject` derived classes. If you want to use it in a view you'll have to derive off `INotifyPropertyChanged` and make your property use the event.